# Free a circular linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I kind of understand how to free them but I'm pretty sure I am doing it wrong in my code.

```
while( *bestFriend != NULL){
                    temptr = *bestFriend;
                    *bestFriend = (*bestFriend)->next;
                    free(temptr);
                    printf("Freed\n");
                }
```

its crashing my program a bit unsure what is causing it though.

Edit: rest of Code

```
int duckDuckBoot(jimmysFriend **bestFriend, int rounds, int howManyDucks, int numberOfFriends, int gameCounter){

    int roundCounter;
    int i;
    jimmysFriend *temptr;
    temptr = *bestFriend;
    roundCounter = 0;
    if(rounds != 0){
     do{
        for(i = 0; i < howManyDucks;){
            i++;
            if(i == howManyDucks){
                    temptr = temptr->next;
                if((*bestFriend)->next == *bestFriend){
                    temptr = *bestFriend;
                    free(temptr);
                    *bestFriend = NULL;
                    printf("Game %d:\n", gameCounter);
                    printf("Jimmy has friends no more\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                else if(temptr->next == *bestFriend){
                 jimmysFriend *temptr2;
                 while(temptr->next->next != *bestFriend){
                        temptr = temptr->next;
                 }

                 temptr2 = temptr->next;
                 temptr->next = *bestFriend;
                 free(temptr2);
                 temptr = *bestFriend;
                }
                else if(temptr == *bestFriend){
                    jimmysFriend *temptr2;
                    temptr2 = *bestFriend;
                    while(temptr->next != *bestFriend){
                        temptr = temptr->next;
                    }
                    temptr->next = (*bestFriend)->next;
                    (*bestFriend) = (*bestFriend)->next;
                    free(temptr2);
                }
                else{
                    jimmysFriend* temptr2;
                    temptr2 = *bestFriend;

                    while(temptr2->next->next != temptr->next){
                        temptr2= temptr2->next;
                    }
                    jimmysFriend *temptr3;
                    temptr3 = temptr;
                    temptr2->next = temptr->next;
                    temptr = temptr->next;
                    temptr2 = NULL;
                    free(temptr3);
                    free(temptr2);


                }
                roundCounter++;
                }
            else{
            temptr = temptr->next;
            }


        }

        }while(roundCounter != rounds);
        if(roundCounter == rounds){
            char** nameList;
            int listSize;
            nameList = allocMemory(numberOfFriends);
            listSize = dataTransfer(*bestFriend, nameList, numberOfFriends);
            printf("Game %d:\n", gameCounter);
            for(i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
                printf("%s\n",nameList[i]);

                }

          for(i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
                    free(nameList[i]);
                    free(nameList);
                }
            while( *bestFriend != NULL){
                    temptr = *bestFriend;
                    *bestFriend = (*bestFriend)->next;
                    free(temptr);
                    printf("Freed\n");
                }


        }







    }


    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You store the node you started at and stop when the current node's next is the starting node.

Comment: @kaylum do you mean my output, or just more of my program?

Comment: @Jude The code. The link explains what and why.

Comment: @kaylum Alright I've added more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
while( *bestFriend != NULL)
```

You forget that this is circular. The next of the last node to be freed will be the first node you freed. This creates a problem since that memory was deallocated from your program. This will cause a segmentation fault.

My suggestion is to not have the list in a circular manor it will make no difference just one next pointer is not filled.

Answer (score 0):

Circular linked list will never point to `NULL`, given it has one or more node.

But you are doing `while( *bestFriend != NULL)` which means that you are not treating the given list as circular.